# Print preview of website

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

first of all thanks for taking the time to read this. I have created a small personal website from html css and some js so far. Everything is going as planned but one small thing is bothering me. When I clicked ctrl+p and looked at the print preview, the entire page becomes distorted. Now i have created many websites in the past and have never used a @media print stylesheet and the sites looked fine in the past. Why is this site not working in print preview. Any tips will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: there might be "@media all stylesheets" that is active which affects the preview

Comment: make the site public, then, people can see what happen with your @media print styleesheet :)